# Google maps an bootstrap modal in while loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I would like to create google map inside my bootstrap modal. I have LAT and LNG in my database and I would like to create bootstrap modal with google map for every shop in my database based on this values. It seems that I have problem but I'm not sure where. I get only part of map inside my modal and all maps are the same even if LAT and LNG are different. This is my first post here. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php include ('includes/connect.php'); ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Contact Page with Single Map Modal</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


    <style>
          body { padding: 10px; background-color:#CCC }
          .map { height: 450px }
        </style>
        </head>

    <body>

           <?php
             //getting results from database

            $query = "SELECT * FROM store";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    //When user clicks on this link it should opet bootstrap modal with google map inside

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <p><a href="#" data-target="<?php echo "#modalmap".$row['ID_STORE'];?>" data-Toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['NAME'];?></a></p>
      </div> 
    <!-- /row -->


 <!-- Creating dynamic id for moral and dynamic id for bootstrap modal body -->

    <?php  $idmodal = "modalmap".$row['ID_STORE'];
            $mapcontainer = "mapcontainer".$row['ID_STORE']; ?>

    <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $idmodal; ?>">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $row['NAME'];?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="<?php echo $mapcontainer; ?>" class="map"></p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </div><!-- /container -->


    <?php   
       /* Getting LAT and LNG from database */
     $lat = $row['LAT']; 
     $lng = $row['LNG']; 
     ?>

    <script>
           var lat = <?php echo $lat; ?>;
           var lng = <?php echo $lng; ?>;


            var var_map;
            var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        function map_init() {     

                var var_mapoptions = {
                  center: var_location,
                  zoom: 14,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  panControl:false,
                  rotateControl:false,
                  streetViewControl: false,
                };


                var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("<?php echo $mapcontainer; ?>"),
                    var_mapoptions);
          }

              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_init);

          //start of modal google map
          $("<?php echo '#'.$idmodal; ?>").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
              google.maps.event.trigger(var_map, "resize");
              var_map.setCenter(var_location);
          });

    </script> 

    <?php } ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop you are overwriting the function `map_init()` and the variables `lat` & `lng`

A better approach:

use a single maps-instance and a single modal. The related data for the links may be stored e.g. via `data-*` attribute. The benefits:

1. better performance(maps-instance must not be created on each click)
2. less map-loads(note that there is a quota for map-loads)

   ```
   <?php include ('includes/connect.php'); ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Contact Page with Single Map Modal</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


   <style>
         body { padding: 10px; background-color:#CCC }
         .map { height: 450px;background:red }
       </style>
       </head>
       <script>



       function map_init() {
         //we need only a single maps-instance for the page     
         if(!$('body').data('map')){
             var var_mapoptions = {
                 zoom: 2,
                 mapTypeControl: false,
                 panControl:false,
                 rotateControl:false,
                 streetViewControl: false,
               };


             $('body').data('map',new google.maps.Map($('<div class="map"/>')[0],
                   var_mapoptions));

           }
           return  $('body').data('map');
         }
         //click-listener for the modal-links
         $(document).on('click','a[data-map]',function(){
           var data=$(this).data('map'),
               map=map_init();

           $('#map_modal')
             //insert map into modal
             .find('.modal-body')
               .append(map.getDiv())
             .end()
             //set title
             .find('.modal-title')
               .text(data.NAME)
             .end()
             //add shown-listener
             .one('shown.bs.modal',function(){
                   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                   map.setCenter({lat:data.LAT,lng:data.LNG});
                   })
             //show the modal
             .modal('show');
         });

   </script>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
   <!-- a single MODAL -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="map_modal">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">NAME</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body"></div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
         </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
       </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div><!-- /.modal -->
   </div>
   <!-- /MODAL -->

          <?php
            //getting results from database

           $query = "SELECT * FROM store";
           $result = mysql_query($query);
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>

   <!-- row -->
     <div class="row">
       <p>
         <!-- store the properties of the entry via data-attribute -->
         <a href="#" 
             data-map="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($row));?>";>
             <?php echo $row['NAME'];?>
         </a>
       </p>
     </div> 
   <!-- /row -->

           <?php } ?>

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```